# How can I Implement an interface on a returned class and keep its data?

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to implement a interface in a class returned by WCF service. How can i do that and keep the data returned by the service?

I have try this:

```
public class ClientDerived: Client, ImyInteface
{
  public string myInterfaceMethod()
  {
    return "MyInterface Implemented";
  }

}
```

And then use it like this:

```
ClientDerived myClient= new ClientDerived();
myClient = (ClientDerived) myService.GetClient();
```

But i get compiled error when casting my base class to derived class type. So my question remains: How can i implement a new interface on a class returned by wcf and keep his data? Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get? And what type does `myService.GetClient()` return?

Comment: The error tell me that i can't convert Client to ClientDerived class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot downcast a class to add functionality. It's just not possible in C#. If all you have is a generic `Animal`, you cannot downcast it to `Cat` just because you want it to meow.

You should, however, be able to add the interface to the *proxy class* that has been automatically generated for you by the WCF framework, i.e., to add `ImyInterface` directly to `Client`. Since the automatically generated classes are `partial` by default, you can just extend them:

```
public partial class Client : IMyInterface
{
    public string myInterfaceMethod()
    {
        return "MyInterface Implemented";
    }
}
```

Note: The proxy class is usually in a subnamespace of your project namespace (e.g. `MyProjectNamespace.MyRemoteService`), so be sure to put your extensions in the same namespace. Check the *Object Browser* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) if you don't know the namespace.

Comment: Ha! ok and how can i do that?

Comment: @ericpap: I've added an example.

Comment: I try this, (modify the partial class) but when i write: "Cliente = serviceClient.Cliente_GetById(myClient.ID_Cliente);" i get this error: "You cannot implicit convert the type 'Ohmio.Client.OhmioService.Clientes' to 'Ohmio.Client.Clientes'"

Comment: Its like the compiler do not recognize my partial class to be the same as the proxy class and create a new class with the same name.

Comment: @ericpap: Exactly. The proxy class is in the `Ohmio.Client.OhmioService` namespace, whereas "your" class is in the `Ohmio.Client` namespace. Change the `namespace` statement in your class file to make the namespaces match.

Comment: You are a genius! it worked just like i need it! Now i can expand my WCF classes on client side! Thank you very much!